# How to change width on hover using tailwindcss

Tags: css, hover, width, tailwind-css

I'm trying to make a div wider on hovering using Tailwind css.
Is this possible? and how?

I've tried the following but it didn't work:

```
class="w-1/3 hover:w-3/5"
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[By default](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/width#responsive-and-pseudo-class-variants), tailwind CSS only generates responsive variants for width utilities. To change the width on hover, you need to add the following

```
variants: {
    width: ["responsive", "hover", "focus"]
}
```

in the `tailwind.config.js` file and then re-build the tailwind CSS file. After this, you will be able to increase the width of elements by hovering over them.